# how can i call specific smartpy tezos contract entrypoint using ConseilJs?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, rpc, smartpy, conseil

I am trying to set UI that allow users to interact with tezos smart contract by pressing some buttons that have to call the corresponding function in the smart contract with relative arguments